# Jquery Postback Issues in Model Dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have attached an image which is my JQUERY MODEL DIALOG IMAGE. I want to do such that, when i click EditLinkButton,

- My DetailView Control gets bind with that assosiated **e.CommandArgument** of the EditLinkButton.
- Page should not postback
- the model dialog should remain open.

But what currently happen is when i click the EditLinkButton, the page postsback and model dialog is closed.

[image: The Image Reference]

How can i get through this? Any Ideas or help will greatly appreciated as i`m stuck into this issue from few days,

MY CODE:

```
function linkbtnTest(abc) {
    $(abc).dialog({
        title: "Shipment Status",

        modal: true,
        open: function (type, date) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
        },
        closeOnEscape: true,
        height: 800,
        width: 800
    });
}
```

MY DetailsView:

```
<div>
            <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceNumber" HeaderText="Invoice Number" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceDate" HeaderText="Invoice Date" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BLNumber" HeaderText="B/L Number" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BLDate" HeaderText="B/L Date" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="VesselName" HeaderText="Vessel Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="VoyageNumber" HeaderText="Voyage Number" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DueDate" HeaderText="Due Date" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BLDate" HeaderText="BLDate" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ContractedShipmentSchedule" HeaderText="Shipment Schedule" />
                </Fields>
            </asp:DetailsView>
        </div>
```

MY StoredProc:

```
    USE [KeyWin]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_Tbl_ShipmentStatus_Update]    Script Date: 10/12/2012 11:33:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Abid Ali>
-- Create date: <3/10/2012>
-- Description: <sp_Tbl_Shipment_Update>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Tbl_ShipmentStatus_Update]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @ShipmentID int,
    @LCStatusID int,
    @InvoiceNumber varchar(50),
    @InvoiceDate varchar(50),
    @BLNumber varchar(50),
    @BLDate varchar(50),
    @VesselName varchar(50),
    @VoyageNumber varchar(50),
    @DueDate varchar(50),
    @ContractedShipmentSchedule varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.


    -- Insert statements for procedure here


    update tbl_ShipmentStatus set LCStatusID = @LCStatusID,
    InvoiceNumber = @InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate = @InvoiceDate,
    BLNumber = @BLNumber, BLDate = @BLDate, VesselName = @VesselName,
    VoyageNumber = @VoyageNumber, DueDate = @DueDate,
    ContractedShipmentSchedule = @ContractedShipmentSchedule
    where ShipmentID = @ShipmentID

END

GO
```

Comment: Consider adding code that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

is the pencil icon a  element? or just an image with a click event?
if the pencil is a button, you need to add or

```
   return false
```

or

```
`event.preventdefault()`
```

This is because a button makes the page post itself, because its want to post a form.

Comment: where do i need to add return false?

Comment: If `linkbtnTest()` is the event handler for the edit button, you would put the `return false;` at the end of that method.